What is the best way to get all tokens of a user(Account) and metadata of tokens?
I have a question.
What is the best way to get all tokens of a user(Account) and metadata of tokens?
I am currently using Web3js and metaplex to get all the information above the node call through Node Call.
In the case of EVM, you can use a contract with a viewer function that can get a lot of information at once, but I know that it is not possible in Solana. As the number of users increases, the Node Call increases hard, so I wonder if I should use something like Indexing Service.

First, you will need to know what standard you are working with.
Fetching token-22 which uses the metadata extension will be different from fetching, spl tokens that use token metadata program for metadata.
Second, you have the option of using an RPC directly that uses the DAS API to fetch tokens with unfurled metadata or using the inbuilt Metaplex functions to do so
To fetch user assets using the Metaplex libraries is as easy as
// fixme: add missing imports

import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import { fetchAllDigitalAssetByOwner, mplTokenMetadata } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
const umi = createUmi(connection);

export const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(
    Uint8Array.from([]) // update with byte array secret 
);
umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplTokenMetadata());

const assets = await fetchAllDigitalAssetByOwner(umi, owner)

Using an RPC provider that supports DAS, you can call the getAssetsByOwner method to get the user assets
const response = await fetch('https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=<api-key>', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "id": "text",
      "method": "getAssetsByOwner",
      "params": {
        "ownerAddress": "4kg8oh3jdNtn7j2wcS7TrUua31AgbLzDVkBZgTAe44aF"
      }
    }),
});
const data = await response.json();

ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/fetch#fetch-all-by-owner
ref: https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api/get-assets-by-owner

To get all tokens of a user and their metadata on Solana using Web3.js and Metaplex, you’re correct that direct node calls can be inefficient as user numbers grow. Unlike EVM, Solana doesn't support viewer functions within contracts to aggregate this data easily.
Instead, consider using an Indexing Service like The Graph or Solana's own indexing solutions (such as Serum Analytics or Solana Beach) which can help you pull large amounts of data more efficiently. These services index blockchain data and provide APIs for quick access, reducing the load on your node calls.
By leveraging these indexing services, you can efficiently manage and fetch token data at scale.
